API_UNAVAILABLE error using GoogleApiClient to open Google Drive Picker in Android
I'm developing an Android app that requires users to select a file from Google Drive using the file picker. I'm using GoogleApiClient with the intention to integrate Google Drive Picker. Authentication with Google Sign-In works seamlessly, but when I attempt to launch the Google Drive Picker, I receive a ConnectionResult with statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE.
My development environment includes the following library versions in my build.gradle file:
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:21.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:17.0.0'

Here's the code I use to initialize GoogleApiClient and attempt to open the file picker:
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                            IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                                    .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
                                    .setMimeType(new String[]{"application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"})
                                    .build(mGoogleApiClient);
                            try {
                                startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, 1001, null, 0, 0, 0);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                Log.e("SettingsActivity", "Unable to send intent", e);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                            // Handle connection suspended
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(connectionResult -> {
                        Log.e("SettingsActivity", "Connection failed: " + connectionResult.toString());
                    })
                    .build();
        }
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

Google Drive and Google Sheets APIs are enabled in the Google Cloud Console for my project, and I've confirmed the google-services.json file is correct and aligned with my project configuration.
Has anyone encountered the same issue or have suggestions on what might be wrong or how to resolve it?
